# JMeter Beanshell problem with imports at top of script: Error invoking bsh method: eval

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am getting a error in a Beanshell Postprocessor, after a HTTP Request returning a JSON array :

My JMeter is launched using `mvn jmeter:configure jmeter:gui` using Maven plugin configured like so:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <executions>
            ....
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <generateReports>true</generateReports>
            <testFilesIncluded>
               ....
            </testFilesIncluded>
            <jmeterVersion>5.4.3</jmeterVersion>
            <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
            <testPlanLibraries>
                <artifact>com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1</artifact>
                <artifact>com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1</artifact>
                <artifact>com.github.javafaker:javafaker:1.0.2</artifact>
            </testPlanLibraries>
            <jmeterExtensions>
                <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-manager:1.6</artifact>
                <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-standard:1.4.0</artifact>
                <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-common:1.4.0</artifact>
                <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras:1.4.0</artifact>
                <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras-libs:1.4.0</artifact>
                <artifact>com.blazemeter:jmeter-parallel:0.11</artifact>
            </jmeterExtensions>
            .....
        .....
```

And my script looks like this:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject;
JSONObject jsonArray;
try {
    jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("value");

//    List<JSONObject> jsonList = new ArrayList();
//    if (jsonArray != null) {
//        for (Object object : jsonArray) {
//            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)object;
//            jsonList.add(jsonObj);
//        }
//    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
log.info("jsonArray: " + jsonArray);
```

So, hoping someone might be able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `` import org.json.simple.JSONArray;  
   import org.json.simple.JSONObject;  import o . . . '' : Variable assignment: 
   jsonArray: Can't assign org.json.simple.JSONArray to org.json.simple.JSONObject
Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error 
   invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: 
   `` import org.json.simple.JSONArray;  import org.json.simple.JSONObject;  import o . . . '' : Variable assignment: jsonArray: Can't assign org.json.simple.JSONArray to org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

I see nothing wrong with this code.  Please help.

This is the problematic line, that throws the error:

```
jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject.get("value");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with the code as well. It seems that the `value` attribute of your response is not a [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) hence your cast fails and you're getting an error. We need to

- see the response body
- know what you're trying to achieve

in order to suggest the best possible option

---

There is something wrong with the overall approach:

1. JMeter already comes with [Json-smart library](https://netplex.github.io/json-smart/) which provides possibility to parse JSON, adding another library is not really needed
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because Groovy provides much better performance comparing to other scripting options
3. Groovy has built-in JSON support so no 3rd-party libraries are required
4. JMeter provides [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) and [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) which can cover 99% of needs when it comes to correlation.

Comment: I was able to get it working by switching to Groovy!   Thanks!   I was using json-simple because I also couldn't get json-smart to work for the same reason.    This isn't an answer to my question, but it is a workaround.